# Is there any cloud service has end to end encryption plus binary diff sync?

Tags: file-synchronization, encryption, cloud-service, cloud-storage, synchronization

I like Dropbox's binary diff sync as we don't need to upload the entire file when there's a minor change, especially useful for large files. But Dropbox doesn't support end to end encryption which is privacy concern. So, I wonder if there is a cloud service that has both ?

Answer (score 2):

To get end-to-end encryption it is inevitable to install a piece of software on your client. Such tools exist and often work with more than one cloud. I would recommend to have a look at [Boxcryptor](https://www.boxcryptor.com/), as far as I know it also supports differential synchronisation.